# How can I deploy a static version of a Wordpress site to a server that does not run Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I have a simple Wordpress site that does not use any features that require code to run. I would like to deploy it on a server as a static site that does not run Wordpress for security and performance reasons.

The server is reachable via FTP. While I would prefer an automatic solution I would not mind getting a local copy or zip file that I can deploy manually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have done the exact same thing for a client, we tried easy solution first i.e. use this awesome plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/really-static/

However it was big news website on multisite (where content was created) and then published to child sites (which we converted into static sites) above plugin faced few issues in this situation, for that we then switched to server side solution, using a very simple utility called wget on server

```
wget -m -k -K -E http://your.domain.com
```

You may study the wget manual in detail for all those awesome things you can do with it, it will produce all html files in a folder with relative urls, so you can copy and paste into any folder and site will work.

Here are few links for help with wget:
http://vaasa.hacklab.fi/2013/11/28/howto-make-a-static-copy-of-joomla-site-with-wget/

Wget Manual for all flags and options
http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html

Really helpful link
https://swsblog.stanford.edu/blog/creating-static-copy-website

By the way all dynamic functions like comments etc will not work, so for that we used third party services like e.g. for comments you may use disqus etc

Comment: Thanks, this is a great answer. I think the really-static plugin might work for my site, but I'll try the wget approach as well.

Comment: Great! Glad to know my answer was helpful to you @Fozi